# On characterization of weak convergence.

Tags: probability-theory

I am reading through Theorem 3.2.5 in Durrett, Probability theory and examples, 4th edition.

How can I prove the following?

Let $ Y_n \rightarrow Y$ a.s.. Then, for any open set $G$, $$\liminf_{n \to \infty} 1_G (Y_n) \geq 1_G (Y)$$ holds.

I know it is equivalent to $$ \liminf_{n \to \infty}1_ {Y_{n}^{-1} (G)}  \geq 1_ {Y^{-1} (G)}  $$ where $Y_{n}^{-1} (G)$, $Y^{-1} (G)$are measurable sets.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\omega$ be any point such that $Y_n(\omega) \to Y(\omega)$. If $\omega \notin Y^{-1}(G)$ the the inequality trivially true since the right side is $0$. If $\omega \in Y^{-1}(G)$ then $Y(\omega) \in G$ and hence $Y_n(\omega) \in G$ for $n$ sufficiently large. Hence  $1_{Y{_n}^{-1}(G)}=1$ for $n$ sufficiently large.. Hence $\liminf 1_{Y{_n}^{-1}(G)} \geq 1=1_{Y^{-1}(G)}$.